# Range Variable storing string variable

Tags: excel

So I run into a problem where I Dim A as range, but when I set A = to cells(1,1) and Cell(1,1) happen to be fill in with a text let say "BB" then A = "BB" instead of range("A1"). Can someone explain to me wat going on.

I Haven't tried anything as I don't know where to start I have been trying to work around it but I cant anymore

Answer (score 1):

`A` is a range - but the default property of `Range` is `value`.

Depending on how you output `A` - the value-property is used.

```vb
Sub test()
Dim A As Range
Set A = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)      'cell content = BB

Debug.Print A.Address, A.Value, A

End Sub
```

Output in the immediate window:

`$A$1          BB            BB`

Answer (score 0):

Then how do I set overwrite the `A` (range Variable) with a new range.
As base of the explanation above if `A = cells(1,1)` and `cells(1,1).value` is `BB`, then `u set A = cells(1,2)` while `cells(1,2).value` is `CC`. That would not overwrite the the `Value` of `cells(1,1)` with the `Value` of `cells(1,2)` but wont change the store range variable of `A`?

Comment: Please do not relate to other awnsers by position. The possition of awnsers may change in the future.